# java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.xxx.x.51 (port 8080): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: java, android, sockets

hi I'm new to android here I'm going to sent some text in the form of
   toast  from one android app to another using socket,here i install both
   app in different android devices, where i configure ip through Edit Text 
   from Message receiver app,when i go through change_URL button the toast 
   message has to display in another app, when i try i got Log
   (connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)) and.....i need help
   if any one already tried this.

-->A class Server_test_send

```
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sender_main_);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_view);
    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
    // this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    //this.serverThread.start();
    testBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TestBtn);
    urlbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeurl);
    changeurl = new Dialog(this);
    changeurl.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    changeurl.setContentView(R.layout.changeurl);
    okbt = (Button) changeurl.findViewById(R.id.okbt);
    utlet = (AutoCompleteTextView) changeurl.findViewById(R.id.urlet);
    urlbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   changeurl.show();
        }
    });
    okbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            path = utlet.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(
                    "doorcameraurlsas",
                    Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp
                    .edit();
            editor.putString("doorcameraurlsas", path);
            editor.commit();
            new SendText().execute(path);
            changeurl.dismiss();
        }
    });
    testBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
  }
 public class SendText extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            String url = strings[0];
            client = new Socket(url, 8080); 
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write("Message from other app"); 
            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();
            client.close(); 
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
      }
      }
     }

 Another Class

 public class MainActivity_Receiver extends Activity  implements          
View.OnClickListener{
private String off;
private Switch enbmode;
private Socket socket;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.60";
ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String message;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        enbmode = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        String str = enbmode.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080); // Server socket
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(" PortID","Could not find the port:4444");
    }
     Log.i("ServerStarted"," with port id :4444");

    while (true) {
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            inputStreamReader = new  
      InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); 
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The Massage from   
          client "+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Message ", " From server "+message);
            inputStreamReader.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.i("Problem","Problem in message reading");
        }
    }
  }
   class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

    }
     }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If a connections get refused, this indicates that the target host was reached, but it refused to accept the connection.

In the standard case this means no socket is listening on the port specified.

Comment: Hey, do you know how to resolve this? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: @eyesenberg: Start a server listening on the ip-address:port you want to connect to.